# More than 1 delimiter in regular expression in csplit command

Tags: regex, unix, split

I'm trying to use csplit command to split a file by 3 strings delimiters, but I'm running into problems. I didn't get cplist to work with a list of delimiters.
This is what I'm trying out:

I have this file:

```
 TRANSHEADER002_XA
 XAL1
 XAL2
 XAL3
 TRANSHEADER001_EXEC
 EXECL1
 EXECL2
 EXECL3
 TRANSHEADER003_YB
 YBL1
 YBL2
 YBL3
 TRANSHEADER002_XA
 XAL1A
 XAL2A
 XAL3A
```

These are the strings delimiters

```
 TRANSHEADER002_XA
 TRANSHEADER001_EXEC
 TRANSHEADER003_YB
```

but I don't get success when I try yo use csplit command with more than 1 delimiter as follows

```
 csplit -k -s -f "$file"_split. "$file" "/^\(TRANSHEADER002_XA\|TRANSHEADER001_EXEC\|TRANSHEADER003_YB\)/" "{999}"
 csplit -k -s -f "$file"_split. "$file" "/^(TRANSHEADER002_XA|TRANSHEADER001_EXEC|TRANSHEADER003_YB)/" "{999}"
 csplit -k -s -f "$file"_split. "$file" "/^TRANSHEADER002_XA|^TRANSHEADER001_EXEC|^TRANSHEADER003_YB/" "{999}"
```

I got an "out of range" error like below for any of the commands above

```
 /^\(TRANSHEADER002_XA\|TRANSHEADER001_EXEC\|TRANSHEADER003_YB\)/ - out of range
```

I want to split that file like below

```
 --> file_split.01
 TRANSHEADER002_XA
 XAL1
 XAL2
 XAL3

 --> file_split.02
 TRANSHEADER001_EXEC
 EXECL1
 EXECL2
 EXECL3

 --> file_split.03
 TRANSHEADER003_YB
 YBL1
 YBL2
 YBL3

 --> file_split.04
 TRANSHEADER002_XA
 XAL1A
 XAL2A
 XAL3A
```

Do you guys know how I could do that by using csplit or by using another command that would gave me the split files like I showed above?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should not repeat the pattern 999 times, but use an option designed to repeat it as many times as necessary: `{*}`:

```
csplit -kszf "$file"_split. "$file" "/^TRANSHEADER002_XA\|TRANSHEADER001_EXEC\|TRANSHEADER003_YB/" "{*}"
```

Also use the `-z` option to remove empty output files.

Comment: I got "csplit: Illegal repeat count: {*}" and "csplit: illegal option -- z"

then I tried this way for example file above:

csplit -ksf "$file"_split. "$file" "/^TRANSHEADER002_XA\|TRANSHEADER001_EXEC\|TRANSHEADER003_YB/" "{3}"

and

csplit -ksf "$file"_split. "$file" "/^TRANSHEADER002_XA|TRANSHEADER001_EXEC|TRANSHEADER003_YB/" "{3}"


both failed with same out of range

csplit: /^TRANSHEADERIBMAPU001_NA\|TRANSHEADERIBMAPU002_EMEA\|TRANSHEADERIBMAPU003_AP/ - out of range

Answer (score 0):

With your sample file this worked for me:

```
csplit -zksf file_split. csplit.test.txt '/^TRANSHEADER\(002_XA\|001_EXEC\|003_YB\)/' '{*}'
```

Using `{*}` eliminates the out-of-range error because it matches as many times as it can, rather than trying exactly 999 times.

I also reduced your regex, but that's beside the point.

(I see Michal beat me to this)

Comment: Didn't work for me. I got following error

csplit: /^TRANSHEADER\(002_XA\|001_EXEC\|003_YB\)/ - out of range

Comment: @Jose - I did this with `csplit (GNU coreutils) 5.97` -- found by running `csplit --version` -- what version are you using, on what flavour of Unix?

Comment: In fact, you might not even have the `--version` arg available if you're not on Linux.